# C# Masked textbox with date format skips first character

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, text, maskedtextbox

I have a problem in a winform app.
I have several masked textbox which use the short date mask (**/**/____), the problem is that if I select all the text (either with Ctrl + a or from code) and I write a new date is like that the first character goes at an 11th position (the mask disappear and i see only the character I wrote) and if I press backspace the text becomes something like this **_1/01/1979** and I have to select all again and press backspace or delete everything.

I handled in this way

```
private void maskedTxt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            MaskedTextBox msk = sender as MaskedTextBox;
            if (msk != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(msk.Text.Replace("/", string.Empty).Replace(":", string.Empty).Trim()) && _focused)
                {
                    _focused = false;
                    SendKeys.SendWait("{BACKSPACE}");
                }
            }
        }
```

_focused is a Boolean variable that I set to true if a validation error happens at the leave event of the masked textbox (invalid date, the date is too big or too small etc...)
so that when someone enters the textbox the text can be written correctly

Is there a better way to handle this "error" or this is good? I tried it and it worked but a lot of people will have to use this application and probably there will be some errors along the way.
Thanks

Comment: Why not just use a `DateTimePicker` - the control actually made for date input?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't, they want me to use a masked textbox since the people who will use the application for the data entry must only use the keyboard in order to work fast.

Comment: The `DateTimePicker` accepts keyboard input.

Comment: Great to know, I will surely use it but that is not the answer that I'm looking for right now because this issue happens with almost every type of mask, thanks anyway